# RapisClipse 11 creating a new project in new workspace generates error: The declared package does not match the expackted package

Tags: rapidclipse

I have a fresh RapidClipse 11 installation, a new empty Workspace on a Win10 Client with the latest updates.
I created a new project with the new project wizard.
Direct after creation and Maven update I got for each auto generated object the following error.
Also the RC11 Project perspective is broken. Under main-java should the folder/package structure be visible, but it isn't.
Closing, reopen, build etc. did not help.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The declared package "com.bosch.purcrtest.ui" does not match the expected package "main.java.com.bosch.purcrtest.ui"    MainContainer.java  /purcrtest/src/main/java/com/bosch/purcrtest/ui line 2  Java Problem
[image: screenshot]

The Questions are, what is wrong, why the project wizard did not work anymore?
How to fix the problem and the RC11 perspective?

Comment: Same issue here. I think we should be writing on their github project.